# Rails 4, Paperclip, Heroku and Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use Heroku and Paperclip using S3 storage. I'm having problems even running it locally, though... I've set up using this:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

I've followed it perfectly, but I'm receiving this error when trying to upload files locally. I'm uploading them using AJAX and the remotipart gem, if that makes a difference Any help would be appreciated! Here are the server logs when I try to upload a file:

```
Started POST "/welcome/upload_avatar" for 192.168.1.2 at 2014-01-17 03:45:03 -0800
Processing by WelcomeController#upload_avatar as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"R7WD+4IbWzm2s0d/XGnrMB+36nHEoRG35ZHcUDTD7iw=", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "temp_avatar"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f3dbc974360 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140117-55338-1412d8u>, @original_filename="mogwai.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"temp_avatar[avatar]\"; filename=\"mogwai.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj20140117-55338-1qle1sa'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj20140117-55338-1qle1sa'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj20140117-55338-1u3rswg'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/mogwai20140117-55338-61cjjj20140117-55338-1u3rswg'
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `avatar_content_type`
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "temp_avatars" ("avatar_content_type", "avatar_file_name", "avatar_file_size", "avatar_updated_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["avatar_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["avatar_file_name", "mogwai.jpg"], ["avatar_file_size", 24307], ["avatar_updated_at", Fri, 17 Jan 2014 11:45:03 UTC +00:00], ["created_at", Fri, 17 Jan 2014 11:45:03 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 17 Jan 2014 11:45:03 UTC +00:00]]
[paperclip] saving /temp_avatars/avatars/000/000/085/original/mogwai.jpg
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 267ms

LoadError (libexslt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so):
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:20:in `block in upload_avatar'
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:19:in `upload_avatar'


  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (11.8ms)
```

Comment: It almost sounds like it's complaining that it can't find nokogiri... Is nokogiri installed?

Comment: In your ruby env just run `gem install nokogiri`